# Totally geodesic submanifold of codimension 1 in noncompact Riemannian manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume that $M$ is a noncompact complete simply connected manifold of nonnegative sectional curvature. Then by Soul theorem, it has a soul $S$.

> **Question 1 :** Fix a point $p\in S$. Then there is a totally geodesic submanifold of codimension 1 passing through $p$

example : In $\mathbb{E}^3$, $z=x^2+y^2$ has a non-selfintersecting infinite geodesic.

> **Question 2 :** If $M$ is a noncompact complete Riemannian manifold and it contains a *line* $l$, then for any $p\in l$, $M$ has a totally geodesic submanifold $N$ of codimension 1 s.t. $N$ intersects the line transversally at $p$.

Comment: I don't understand the "proof" part. What are you trying to prove ? What is $p_i$ ?

Comment: Sorry. I editted.

Comment: I still don't understand the proof part. What does "Yim" mean? What is the verb in the sentence comprising the proof?

Comment: After arbitrarily small perturbation (in your favourite topology) of any Riemannian metric on any manifold of dimension 3 or more, I believe that there are no codimension 1 totally geodesic submanifolds, although I don't have a proof at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Question 1:** As Ben McKay pointed out, a generic Riemannian manifold of dimension $n\ge 3$ does not have totally geodesic hypersurfaces; see ["About every convex set..."](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15189) by Alexander Lytchak and me.

**For Question 2:** If you still assume that curvature is nonnegative, then the statement follows from the [splitting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_theorem); moreover, $N\perp \ell$.
If you do not assume nonnegative curvature, then the answer is "no" for the same reason as in Question 1.